# Which one is the correct way of writing this and why?

Tags: pronoms

Which one is correct? and why?

> Nous sommes toi et moi

or

> C'est toi et moi

Comment: The correct way of writing what?

Answer (score 3):

La première phrase, en isolation, ne signifie pas grand chose ; si on complète ce début de façon appropriée on obtient des phrases significatives ; il semble cependant que, du moins dans certains cas, il soit préférable de détacher l'apposition « toi et moi » du reste de la phrase par des virgules d'encadrement.

- Nous sommes toi et moi les seuls à s'être adressés au chef du personnel.
- Nous sommes toi et moi maintenant mariés et c'est pour toujours.
- Nous sommes toi et moi trop fatigués pour continuer et il vaut mieux que nous prenions du repos.
- Nous sommes, toi et moi, tu l'auras remarqué, les malchanceux dans cette histoire.

La seconde forme est correcte telle qu'écrite, sans additions.

Elle s'utilise en particulier pour des réponse.

- -- Qui est le groupe délégué ? 
  --C'est toi et moi.
- -- Qui sont ces deux-là ? Je n'ai jamais vu cette photo, il me semble. 
  -- C'est toi et moi !

Le pourquoi est assez difficile à comprendre ; c'est une tournure idiomatique du français ; les français ont préféré le pronom démonstratif « ce » au pronom personnel de la troisième personne comme en anglais (It's him.).

D'après le TLFi on dit que « ce » a une valeur anaphorique<sup>1</sup> ; dans cette même source on trouve que « ce » est sujet d'une proposition dite attributive d'identification : c'est moi (toi, lui, elle), ce sont eux (elles), (familier) c'est eux (elles).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Se dit d'un terme grammatical qui permet de rappeler un mot ou groupe de mots précédemment énoncé.</sub>